# Newton method implementation in matlab

Tags: matlab

I wanted to implement the newton method. My code is so far:

f is a function-handle, df the differentiate f (also a function-handle) and x is the start value.

It works for some functions, but for example when I ask for

```
newton(@(x) x^2,@(x) 2*x,1)
```

it comes in an infinite loop. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual check for termination for Newton's method is to see if the result of another iteration is "very close" to the previous answer, but you're using the check:

```
if abs(xn) == abs(x)
```

which basically requires the two values to be identical (except you've used `abs`, which is a bug since it would accept an answer that's so wrong that an iteration flips the sign).  For some problems, this might work, but this is very likely to lead to an infinite loop with the iterations cycling through a set of very close values.

Change your termination test to:

```
if abs(xn-x) < 0.0000001    (or something else very small)
```

which tests to see if `xn` and `x` differ by no more than the very small value given, and that should work.

Comment: Since the root of x^2=0 is 0, that *is* the root to within 0.0000001.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Is there any way to make MATLAB give back 0 when the number is very small?

Comment: Is there any way to calculate the exact roots (to compute the divisions)?

Comment: What do you mean by "to compute the divisions"?

Comment: For example when I ask for newton(@(x) x^2 - 2, @(x) 2*x, 1), I get 886731088897/627013566048, which is ~1.14. But I want MATLAB to show 1.14 instead of the division.

Comment: You can use the `round` function to round to a fixed number of decimal places.  Will that do what you want?